# Selection Start Row in DatagridView

Tags: c#

I am using the windows DataGridView, in this grid i allowed the multiple rows selection.

When i am checking the `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index` it's giving last selected rows  Index. Just i want from which row the selection started(Start Row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
Int32 selectedRowCount = 
        dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[selectedRowCount - 1 ].Index.ToString();
```

Comment: Its changed something in grid row selection(Avoided Cell Selection) and using above code its working ..........Thank you Candie

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach loop to check the lowest indexed Row.
Because Rows in SelectedRows collection are added in order as you select the row.

Here is complete foreach loop..

```
        int i=int.MaxValue;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            if (rw.Index < i)
            {
                i = rw.Index;
            }
        }

        DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
```

it will return you lowest indexed selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1].Index
```

But from my point of view, the selection order in the `SelectedRows` is not something that should be relied on anyway. As far as I know, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) doesn't specify any particular order... You should do something by yourself if that's important for your application.